# Calculate sum of price of the checked row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap-table and in the last column there's a checkbox.

When I check or uncheck a checkbox, I'd like it to calculate the sum of the price of the checked items.

http://jsfiddle.net/34x9zdv4/

```
function calculate() {
  var total = 0;
  $("#tableTest tr td input:checked").closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4)").each(
    function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this.text()));
    }
   );
   alert(total);
}
```

The alert never shows up. This is what happens: .text is unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the following line.

```
total += parseFloat($(this.text()));
```

It should be

```
total += parseFloat($(this).text());
```

Note the brackets around `this` which you previously had around `this.text()`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have your parentheses in the wrong order.

Change:

```
$(this.text())
```

Into:

```
$(this).text();
```

So your summation line should look like:

```
total += parseFloat($(this).text());
```